# Syrian Custom re: Nine Days

Tags: minhag, nine-days, syrian

Anyone have information on the Syrian minhag re: wearing freshly laundered clothing during the Nine Days? Does Rav Eli Mansour say anything about this?

Comment: If only you knew a Syrian rabbi you could ask directly ;)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, Sephardim do not observe the restriction of not wearing freshly laundered clothing from Rosh Chodesh Av, but [as held by Rav Ovadia Yosef](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2077) rather only on the week of Tisha B'Av itself.

On years like this one where Tisha B'av falls out on Saturday and the Fast is observed on Sunday, Rabbi Mansour [holds as per his Halacha Yomit page](https://itorah.com/daily-halacha/lecture/the-status-of-the-week-of-tisha-b-ab-when-it-falls-on-sunday/2347) that there are those who observe these customs on the week leading up to Shabbat, and those who don't, and both are acceptable.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Why thank you, @Shalom!